# smallest single positive integer to be added to make two arrays equal

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays

```
arr1=[1,1,7,2] and arr2=[1,13,2,1]
```

The output should be like `6 1`

I need to find the smallest single positive integer element that can be added to any one of the elements of any of the arrays to make them equal. This case will only occur if the difference in the arrays is 1. I am checking that using the condition

```
sizeof(array_diff($arr1, $arr2)) == 1
```

I need to return both the smallest single positive integer element that can be added and to which array it should be added.

I am new to php, any help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean the sum of them? What is the answer to your example?

Comment: I have edited the question, you can now check.

Comment: What is the condition that a number has to fullfill to be `the smallest single positive integer element that can be added to any one of the elements`, other than that is is a positive integer?

Comment: And if i get you right, should the result not be `6 7 1`, because you have to add 6 to the 7 of the first array to make both equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your question you want the output to be the difference in sum and the No of the array:

```
$array1 = array(1,1,7,2);
$array2 = array(1,13,2,1);

$sum1 = array_sum($array1);
$sum2 = array_sum($array2);

$result = $sum1 - $sum2;
$difference = abs($sum1 - $sum2);

print_r($difference." ");

if($result<0)
  print_r("1");
else
  print_r("2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but here's my guess at what you want:

```
$arr1 = [1, 1, 7, 2];
$arr2 = [1, 13, 2, 1];

$arr1Sum = array_sum($arr1);
$arr2Sum = array_sum($arr2);

if ($arr1Sum == $arr2Sum) {
    echo "No difference";
} elseif ($arr1Sum < $arr2Sum) {
    echo "Add " . ($arr2Sum - $arr1Sum) . " to \$arr1";
} elseif ($arr1Sum > $arr2Sum) {
    echo "Add " . ($arr1Sum - $arr2Sum) . " to \$arr2";
}
```

[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/935434)

It just compares the sum of both arrays, if `$arr1` is less than `$arr2`, then we know that we need to add the difference to `$arr1`.

If my guess is wrong, then update your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the arrays and compare them in a foreach loop.

```
$arr1=[1,1,7,2];
$arr2=[1,13,2,1];

Sort($arr1);
Sort($arr2);

Foreach($arr1 as $key => $val){
    If($val>$arr2[$key]){
        Echo "arr1 key" . $key .": ".  ($val-$arr2[$key]). "\n";
    }Elseif($arr2[$key]>$val){
        Echo "arr2 key" . $key .": ".  ($arr2[$key]-$val). "\n";
    }Else{
        Echo "equal\n";
    }
}
```

Not sure how you get to `6 1` I see it as only `6`.

https://3v4l.org/OtmWF